# the result should be 160 and i don't know the problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

the if condition don't work
the result should be 160 and i don't know the problem

```py
def addition(*numbers ):
    for nums in numbers :
        if nums == 10 :
            
            continue
        elif nums ==5:
            nums = nums-5
            
            return nums
        
    return sum(nums)

print(addition((10, 20, 30, 10, 15, 5, 100)) )
```

Comment: There's a random `def addition(*numbers ):` thrown in there which would surely cause an error if you ran this code. Its indentation is slightly off too. It seems like you might have messed up pasting your code here. The indentation seems slightly off in general; the `if nums == 10 :` statement has no body, for example, which should also result in an error.

Comment: @RandomDavis Looks like the first three lines are repeats. I deleted them and got the code to run

Comment: What do you expect `nums` to be when doing the sum?

Comment: @PaulM. This doesn't print 0. It prints 190 (the sum of all the numbers)

Comment: Ah, yes - then `nums` will be a tuple, rather than an int.

Comment: What is `nums = nums-5` supposed to do? You set `nums` to zero but you do nothing with it. Are you supposed to skip over numbers that are `5` or `10`? If so then the result is 165. I just don't get what the actual functionality is supposed to be since it's not apparent to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def addition(*numbers ):
num = 0
for nums in numbers :
    if nums == 10:
        continue
    elif nums == 5:
        num = num - 5
        continue
    else:
        num = num + nums
        
return num

print(addition(10, 20, 30, 10, 15, 5, 100))
```

This code will do it. You just need to have a number (`num`) where the values are actually added. This will produce 160. Also, as @RandomDavis said, you had too many parenthesis in `print(addition(10, 20, 30, 10, 15, 5, 100))`

Comment: Ohhh, you figured it out; OP was using the name `nums` as the accumulator as well as the loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate version that uses a `list`:

```
def addition(*numbers):
    nums = []
    for num in numbers:
        if num == 10:
            continue
        elif num == 5:
            nums.append(-5)
        else:
            nums.append(num)
    return sum(nums)


print(addition(10, 20, 30, 10, 15, 5, 100))
```

What needed changing:

1. You were passing a tuple of numbers instead of the numbers themselves to `addition` (there was an extra set of parentheses)
2. You were using `nums` as a temporary variable to store each list item as you iterated through the list, but you were also treating it as if it was an accumulator that you were adding the numbers to; when you had `nums = nums-5` all that was doing was causing the current temporary `nums` variable to be set to zero. And then you had a `return` in there so that was being returned right away, before the loop could finish.
3. You had `sum(nums)` at the end; but `sum()` only works for a collection. Yet `nums` was just a number, so if you tried to run that code it would crash.
4. You were not using a list or an accumulator variable to keep track of the sum. You could have either had a number that you added to or subtracted from, or a list that you appended items to. If you were using a number to store the sum you could just return that number at the end. If you were using a list you could return the sum of the list and the end (as I did in my example).
5. You were not tallying up the numbers from the `*numbers` argument; they were not being added to a list of any kind, or added to a variable that was being used to keep track of the sum. You were just looping through numbers and doing nothing with them, essentially.